# log access to code repo in visual studio online

Tags: azure-devops

When using visual studio online, we want to ensure that contractors or developer working on project could only check-in and check-out using our given laptops.

1. Has anyone found a way to restrict access to code from a certain machines in Visual studio Online?
2. Can we somehow log who checked code out and from which machine at what time?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to restrict access to VSO by IP address. It is something we are considering. What you can do is to enable [two-factor authentication](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/multi-factor-authentication/) in your Azure Active Directory tenant.

There's no way to currently log who has checked out code. The closest you could get would be to periodically query for the workspaces in the account if you are using TFVC. There's no way for you to track clones of Git repos.